# Why does it work -> key : 'hey' ->'hey' and doesnt throw any error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the following code work in javascript ?

```
key : 'hey'
```

logs :

```
'hey'
```

on the console

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: JFYI: `{ key: 'hey' }` is either an object, or as a statement it is a block statement with a labelled 'hey' ...

Comment: Its Just a single line of code. Not an Object.
key : 'hey'

Answer (score 6):

Because in that code, `key:` defines a [*statement label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). The label is followed by an *expression statement* which is just a string literal. Statements have result values (this is not commonly known) which you cannot directly observe in code, but can in the Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop (REPL) of the browser console, which shows the value resulting from the last statement.

Statement labels are those things you can use to break an outer loop from an inner one:

```js
outer: for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        console.log(i, i, i * j);
        if (i * j === 2) {
            console.log("breaking outer");
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It didnt strike me that its statement - label. :)